# Convert pointer to its primary value in json decoder

Tags: json, pointers, go

How can I convert `*string` to `string`?

Heres my error code:

> cannot use m.Body (type *string) as type string in argument to
>   strings.NewReader

Here is my code:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(m.Body))
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here with the downvotes

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of basic questions about the language. You might want to go through the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/), which coincidentally has a section demonstrating how to use pointers.

Comment: Ok Ill read throguh that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereference the pointer to get the value of `string` from `*string` and then use it in `strings.NewReader` function. For eg:-

```
strValue := *m.Body
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(strValue))
```

For working example check [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4JIFa5oQxvx)

Comment: cannot use strValue (type *string) as type string in argument to strings.NewReader